# Change default GET response for Jenkins/IBM HTTP Webserver

Tags: jenkins, load-balancing, ibmhttpserver

Jenkins is running behind IBM HTTP Webserver, and the Load Balancing is trying to monitor the Webserver for the error code to check if the Webserver is Up.

Because the security is enabled on Jenkins, `GET/` call from Load Balancer is returning `403 Forbidden`, is there a way this can be redirected or print "`200 OK`" instead, if the page is reached, rather returning "403"?

Also tried using the Rewrite engine in the httpd file

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ProxyPass         /  http://AppServer:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse  /  http://AppServer:8080/
    ProxyRequests     Off
    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

    RewriteEngine  on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^curl/*
    RewriteRule ^/index.php$
</VirtualHost>
```

Still doesn't work. I am sure, my configuration in the httpd file not correct, any suggestions? index.php is placed in bin directory of the HTTP server.

Answer (score 0):

You could use mod_rewrite to send requests for ^/$ with a user-agent of your monitoring script to some other static resource

Comment: Looks like mod_rewrite is the way to go, however, did not work in my case. I have revised my question to include the VirtualHost configuration.